# Repartitioning in Hadoop Distributed File System ( HDFS )

Tags: hadoop

Is there a way to repartition data directly in HDFS? If You notice that Your partitions are unbalanced (one or more is much bigger then other) how You can deal with it?

I know that it could be done ex in Apache Spark but running a job to just repartition seems like overhead- or maybe it is good idea?

Comment: What do you refer to as "repartition"? Do you want to spread data evenly across all data nodes? Or you are referring to Hive/Impala table partitions?

Comment: I want to spread data across all data nodes using only HDFS

Answer (score 1):

Run `hdfs balancer`. This tool that distributes HDFS blocks evenly across datanodes.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#balancer

In case you are running a Cloudera Manager or Ambari managed distribution, you can run HDFS balancer from their web UI.